How to parse animated values in react native?
I want to parse the values shown in the <Animated.Text>.
I want only integer values not fractionated ones.
I'm getting this:

I want that:

I tried using:
<Animated.Text>{Number.parseInt(milliliters.ml)}</Animated.Text>

But I get errors, It doesn't work.
My example running online:
https://snack.expo.dev/@danilobatistaqueiroz/parsing_animated_values
If there is another library for this type of animation, it's enough for my case.
My code:
import { Animated, Easing } from 'react-native';
import React from 'react';

export default function Milliliters() {

  const ML_LEVELS = [240,50,190];
  this.ml = React.useRef(new Animated.Value(ML_LEVELS[0])).current;

  this.ml_up_down = ()=>{
    Animated.sequence([
      Animated.timing(this.ml, {
        duration: 2000,
        toValue: ML_LEVELS[1],
        easing: Easing.bezier(.55,.5,.45,.5),
        useNativeDriver: false,
        delay: 0,
      }),
      Animated.timing(this.ml, {
        duration: 2000,
        toValue: ML_LEVELS[2],
        easing: Easing.ease,
        useNativeDriver: false,
        delay: 0,
      }),
    ]).start();
  }

}

import Milliliters from './milliliters';

import React from 'react';
import { Animated, Text } from 'react-native';

export default AddDrink = () => {

 const milliliters = React.useRef(new Milliliters()).current;

 React.useEffect(() => {
   milliliters.ml_up_down();
 });

 return (
   <Animated.Text>{milliliters.ml}</Animated.Text>
 );

}

